# Complex analysis exercise: prove that $f$ is constant given an inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I am studying complex analysis and I came upon this exercise:

> If $f$ is a holomorphic function in $\mathbb{C}$ and for every $z\in\mathbb{C}$ we have
> $|f(z)|\leq\sqrt{|z|+2}$ then show that $f$ is a constant function.

Any ideas for solving this problem? I tried with Liouville's theorem, but I think that it isn't the right way to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the proof of Liouville's theorem: select your favorite complex number $a$ and let $r > |a|$. Cauchy's integral formula states that
$$ f'(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^2} \, dz.$$
Investigate the integrand: if $|z| = r$ then $$|f(z)| \le \sqrt{|z| + 2} = \sqrt{r + 2}$$ and
$$|z-a| \ge |z| - |a| = r - |a|,$$
which lead to the estimate
$$|f'(a)| \le \frac 1{2\pi} \int_{|z| = r} \frac{|f(z)|}{|z-a|^2} |dz| \le \frac{r\sqrt{r+2}}{(r-|a|)^2}.$$
Let $r \to \infty$ to conclude $f'(a) = 0$.